# Where em um select em um sístema que usa um tipo de relacionamento muitos para muitos

Tags: sql, sqlite3, knex.js

Estou fazendo um sistema básico que tem uma tabela de `projects`, uma de `tags` e uma tabela pivô, `project_tag`. Cada `project` tem um `id`, `title` e uma `tag`. A tabela de `tags` tem um `id` e um `title` . A tabela `projeto_tag` tem um `projeto_id` e um `tag.id`, logo, cada projeto tem uma tabela para cada tag, fazendo assim um relacionamento de muitos para muitos. Segue as tabelas a baixo:

**Tabela de project:**

```
CREATE TABLE projects (
    user_id    INTEGER,
    id         INTEGER  NOT NULL
                        PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title      TEXT,
    create_at  DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (
        user_id
    )
    REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
                          ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

**Tabela de tags:**

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
    id  INTEGER       NOT NULL
                      PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    tag VARCHAR (255) 
);
```

**Tabela project_tag:**

```
CREATE TABLE project_tag (
    id         INTEGER NOT NULL
                       PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    project_id INTEGER,
    tag_id     INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (
        project_id
    )
    REFERENCES projects (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
                             ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (
        tag_id
    )
    REFERENCES tags (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
                         ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Quero filtrar os projetos com base nas tags que um usúario passou, exemplo:

`['React.js', 'Knex', e por ai vai...]`

,porém, bom, pelo menos da forma que eu estou selecionando, tá retornando um para cada tag que ele tem, não todas as juntas, o que dificulta o processo de where, eu acho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Visto isso, eu não consigo fazer um `where` que satisfaça a minha vontade, que é filtrar os projetos com base nas tags que eu passei, por exemplo: se eu passar a tag "React.js", retornar todos os projetos que tenham essa tag e também as outras. Pesquisei algumas formas, mas não encontrei.

**Observação**: eu estou utilizando o *Knex* no back-end e meu banco de dados é o *SQlite3*. Código em *SQL* que está fazendo o select e gerando o retorno da quarta imagem:

```
SELECT projects.id, tags.tag, tags.id FROM projects 
INNER JOIN project_tag on project_tag.project_id = projects.id 
INNER JOIN tags on project_tag.tag_id = tags.id
```

Comment: Não foi informado banco de dados, mas já tentou a clausula `WHERE tags.tag IN("React.js", "Knex")`

Comment: Já. O problema é que como tá retornando várias colunas, uma para cada tag, ainda que o projeto não tivesse a tag "Knex", ele retornaria o projeto com a tag "React". Exemplo: um projeto que tenha  as tags "React.js" e "Angular"

Comment: Detalhe o seu modelo de dados colocando na pergunta o SQL das tabelas envolvidas na operação, o nome do Banco de Dados(Importante para definir a sintaxe SQL a ser usada) e se possível uma amostra dos dados para podermos replicar o seu problema.

Comment: Dei uma refatorada na pergunta para tentar deixar ela um pouco mais clara, obrigado.

Comment: Cadê os `CREATE TABLE` para replicar o seu problema?

Comment: Refatorei novamente, amigo

Comment: @Junior3874, da forma como você colocou, a gente teria que digitar a dedo tudo que está dentro das imagens. Com o texto selecionável, a gente pode só copiar e colar num ambiente de teste pra reproduzir seu problema e tentar ajudar.

Comment: Alterei já, amigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça um filtro usando as clausulas:

- `WHERE nome_da_coluna IN(valor+)`:
  Onde a cláusula `WHERE` determina quais linhas deverão ser retornadas segundo um critério, operador `IN` permite que você especifique um conjunto de valores para testar pertinência.
  `nome_da_coluna` é a coluna que contém os valore a serem usados pela filtragem.
  `valor+` são um ou mais valores usados como parâmetro de filtragem
- `GROUP BY nome_da_coluna HAVING COUNT(*) = quantidade_de_valores`:
  A cláusula `GROUP BY` especifica que os resultados devam ser agrupados e a cláusula `HAVING` especifica que devam ser retornadas apenas grupos que atendam às condições especificadas.
  `nome_da_coluna` é a coluna que determina como se dará o agrupamento. `quantidade_de_valores` determina a contagem de repetições dentro do grupo para determinar se o grupo foi aprovado ou não.

Exemplos:

Selecionar todos os projetos que possuam ambas as tags *"React.js"*, *"Knex"*:

```
SELECT projects.id AS 'Project ID', tags.tag, tags.id  AS 'Tag ID' FROM projects 
INNER JOIN project_tag on project_tag.project_id = projects.id 
INNER JOIN tags on project_tag.tag_id = tags.id 
WHERE tags.tag IN("React.js", "Knex")
GROUP BY projects.id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Selecionar todos os projetos que possuam ao menos uma das tags *"React.js"*, *"Knex"*:

```
SELECT projects.id AS 'Project ID', tags.tag, tags.id  AS 'Tag ID' FROM projects 
INNER JOIN project_tag on project_tag.project_id = projects.id 
INNER JOIN tags on project_tag.tag_id = tags.id 
WHERE tags.tag IN("React.js", "Knex")
GROUP BY projects.id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Selecionar todos os projetos que não possuam as tags *"React.js"*, *"Knex"*:

```
SELECT projects.id AS 'Project ID', tags.tag, tags.id  AS 'Tag ID' FROM projects 
INNER JOIN project_tag on project_tag.project_id = projects.id 
INNER JOIN tags on project_tag.tag_id = tags.id 
WHERE tags.tag IN("React.js", "Knex")
GROUP BY projects.id HAVING COUNT(*) = 0
```

Comment: Perfeito, cara. Atendeu perfeitamente o que eu queria.